# How to horizontally align all input button with all other items

Tags: html, css, forms

I am wanting to make a form where all the fields, and the input buttons are perfectly horizontally aligned.  I tried setting `margin: 0 auto` on all the items (after resetting the css) but it seems like the length of the text fields make it so the items do not look horizontally center (the input button takes up much less space).  Is there an easy way to offset this difference in widths **without** using absolute positioning (I want this to be responsive).

Here is the html:

```
<h1>
    Please upload your file
</h1>
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple" ><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

And the css:

```
h1, form {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    margin-top: 1.2em;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

p {
    margin-top: .2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

input {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

input[type=submit] {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

And here is the issue I am mentioning. (I would like the `choose files` button centered)[image]

Comment: Check the HTML you have uploaded.It is not for above image.Add appropriate HTML

Comment: file button dont have the same look on all browser. you may need to change it to custom. So it can look the same on all browser and then align it to center.

Comment: Yes as @Tushar has mentioned, the upload file control is not the same in every browser.  In fact I think every browser renders it a little differently.  Check this blog out from css-tricks. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-file-input-styling-webkitblink/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a border to your input fields to make it clear that it's centre aligned:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6TL2/)

```
input {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}
```

Comment: ohhh I like that although I was trying to make it as minimal as possible.  Would it be possible to move the filename under the button and center it that way?

Comment: @Startec note, that css will blanket adds a border to all input fields, including the button. You may want to update the html/css to apply specific classes to specific controls.

Comment: @Startec the chosen file name is part of the file control, not sure you can break it out of there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting input to a relative position and reposition from there:

```
input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Won't the use of `25px`cause problems when used in a responsive page (all other length measurements I am using are relative)

Comment: `releative` should be used , because screen size may change!